# Subject in x-forwarded-client-cert

Tags: istio

In Istio, under what conditions can I expect the `subject` line to be non-empty in the `x-forwarded-client-cert`?  Right now I'm just doing very basic research and testing and I have the SPIFFE `By` and `URI` but the subject is empty.  My assumption is the `subject` would be non-empty if the cert wasn't autogenerated or the connection was from an external ingress.